# q-io/fs in express request handler

Tags: node.js, express, q

I a trying to solve a programming problem in node js that needs to a rad a file.
What is the right way to do this using qio.

Here is my program

```
var express = require('express')
var qfs = require('q-io/fs')
var q = require('q')
var fs = require('fs')
var app = express()
app.get('/books', function(req, res){
  qfs.read(process.argv[3])
  // .then( function(buf){res.json(JSON.parse(buf))})
  // .done()
 .then(res.send).done()
 /*  .then(null, function(abc, err){
            res.json(err)
            console.log("Error handler")
            res.status(500)
          })*/
  })
 app.listen(process.argv[2])
```

I know I can read file synchronously, also the following code works

```
qfs.read(process.argv[3])
.then( function(buf){res.json(JSON.parse(buf))})
.done()
```

but the main code gives error, I understand this is because the app object has gone out of scope because the request handler has probably already returned.

```
/home/ubuntu/mahesh/node_tries/node_modules/q/q.js:155
                throw e;
                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'req' of undefined
    at send (/home/ubuntu/mahesh/node_tries/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:103:17)
    at _fulfilled (/home/ubuntu/mahesh/node_tries/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/ubuntu/mahesh/node_tries/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/ubuntu/mahesh/node_tries/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /home/ubuntu/mahesh/node_tries/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (/home/ubuntu/mahesh/node_tries/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/home/ubuntu/mahesh/node_tries/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
```

What is happening here?? At what point does the handler for express.js return when res.end is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late, but I stumbled upon this problem myself and wanted to help anyone who encounters this in the future.

The line on which your program fails, in response.js, is this one:

```
var req = this.req;
```

When res.send() is invoked, the function send is invoked with the context of res (so "this" is res), and this.req is the request object.

However, when you passed the function as a variable to the promise, it lost the context and became just a function. So, when it was invoked, "this" was undefined and this.req became an error. So to fix your problem, replace

```
.then(res.send).done()
```

with

```
.then(books => res.send(books)).done()
```